# Remove ActiveAdmin automatic link when resource/page exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'll preface this by saying I know little to nothing about Ruby on Rails. I inherited a RoR project and have to make some minor changes that the documentation for ActiveAdmin does not list. Seems like a minor change like removing an anchor link should be simple, but it's not. Here is the code block I'm working with:

```
div do
  panel("Child Licenses") do
    table_for(user.desktop_licenses) do
      column :id do |license|
        link_to license.id, license
      end
      column :parent_license do |license|
        license.license
      end
      column :expires_at
      column :created_at
    end
  end
end
```

I have a panel with a table inside displaying a couple columns of data. The license.id links to a page for the appropriate license id, which is correct, but the license.license in the second column has a corresponding parent license page that automatically links to the parent license page. I want to remove that automatic link from the license.license column, but all the Googling in the world doesn't seem to turn up anything for me. I've looked at the `auto_link` Ruby method and tried messing around with that, but my limited knowledge of Ruby is hindering me. Is there any sort of filter for ActiveAdmin that can just turn off the automatic linking on that one line?

I came across this url https://gorails.com/forum/remove-activeadmin-automatic-link-on-show-view that asks the same question probably in a better way if that helps for context. That is what I'm trying to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `license.license` will go to parent license `show` page?

Comment: `license.license` creates an auto link to the parent license show page. In this case it creates a <a> tag that displays something like a link with the text Demo that is clickable. All I am trying to do is display the text Demo and remove the <a> tag, essentially disabling the auto linking on it. I hope that makes sense. This auto linking is new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to

```
column "Parent license" do |license|
  span { license.license.name }
end
```

if there is name attribute to license else you can show what ever attribute you want to display.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! On a side note. If I don't know all of the attributes available to display, is there a way to just display the object on the page? I know with JS and say JSON objects in other frameworks you can just output the actual object to the page and it will list the object and all of its values. Is there something like this in Rails? That is probably a separate question...just curious. Thank you for your help again!

Comment: Did you mean displaying all `license` attributes in show page?

Comment: Yes. For example if I were able to just display the `license` object  and it would display something like:
`{
  license: 
    id: 1234,
    license: {
      name: "Demo",
      attr1: "someattr",
      attr2: "someattr"
    }
}`
or something like that to see the data structure and then modify it. Basically a way to peak into the data object without having access to the database. In my case, I don't know what attributes I have access to in order to display anything to start with and didn't know that .name was an option. Being able to output the data and modify would be helpful.

Comment: If you resource `license` as `activeadmin` resource it will by default display them

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
column :parent_license do |license|
  license.license
end
```

into

```
column "Parent license" do |license|
  span { license.license.to_s }
end
```

I think this will prevent AA's magic kicking in. Good luck!

Comment: I was hopeful, but that didn't work. That returned `#<License:0x00007f881edf3d30>` inside the <span> tag. What does the .to_s do?

Comment: The `.to_s` is a method on the License instance. Providing a `def to_s` method in your License model should fix this. What columns are available in your license model? But? Did the link disappear?